# Pytest file path error for relative import

Tags: python, pytest, filepath

I have the following path problems when running pytest. Below is my directory,

```
|- project
  |- src
    |- app
      |- functions
         |- functionA.py
      |- db
         |- dbA.py
  |- tests
    |- app
      |- functions
         |- testFunctionA.py
      |- db
         |- testDbA.py
```

In my functionA.py file, I import db connections like:

```
from app.db.dbA import client
```

However, when in my test file I import the functions like this:

```
from src.app.function.functionA import funcA
```

This results in module not found error named 'app' when i run
`python -m pytest` from `project` directory.

Appreciate if anyone can give tips on how to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: you have any `__init__.py` files in dirs?

Comment: As @Shod said you have no __init__.py so directories are not considered as module and cannot be imported. Have a look to this page that proposes different valid layouts for tests.